# CSS: Using a class for 'position: relative', 'position: fixed' etc - is it a good idea?

Tags: css, class, position

Somewhere along the line I decided that having classes for position would be a good thing. So I created the following:

```
.prel {position: relative}
.pfix {position: fixed}
.pabs {position: absolute}
```

These classes are apply to thousands of little elements floating around, but they're beginning to bug me.

The elements to which my relative position class applies, for example, all belong to about seven other classes. So I could just do this (where class1-class7 are all existing classes used for other purposes):

```
.class1,.class2...class7 {position: relative}
```

The reason for the question is this: I have this sneaking feeling that this is going to be one of those changes I make that I need to reverse out later. So I'm looking for advice as to which is the best way forward. Does it make a difference at all? Why do big sites seem to use these position classes?

I do lot of jQuery class-based searches if that is significant.

Comment: If it's really thousands of element I wouldn't bother changing them. It's a fairly good technique and it doesn't need any change the way I see it. :)

Comment: @BramVanroy  It really is thousands :)  I'd be interested in your response to Jezen's answer, given that he takes the opposite point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, it's a bad idea. It's not really any different from applying inline styles to all your elements. Best practice is good separation of style and content.

As you've already mentioned, you will most likely need to change out loads of these classes later. It's going to be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Let me clarify what the "it" is :)  Is having classes a bad idea (contra to @BramVanroy above) or my idea of getting rid of them?

Comment: There are always exceptions to rules like this, but in my opinion, having a class name that describes the presentation rather than the functionality is a very bad idea from a maintenance point of view.

Comment: Yeah, OK. So would you arrange your CSS so that `position: relative` is in with all the other styling for each class/id, even if that means you have it repeated, say, 15 times though the CSS?  Nice website, BTW :)

Comment: I don't understand why this is a bad idea. Let's say you have *x* elements with different positionings (relative, fixed, absolute, static) which are assigned so by classes. If you would need to change a position of an element, you only need to change its class and that's it. When you have assigned a position to every individual element, you waste a lot of space. I.e. you have to write the position of the specific element every time. When you want to change that position, you need to change it in CSS as well. So the only difference is that when assigning to individual elements, it's more code.

Comment: There are of course different strategies you can employ inside your stylesheet. You can group elements together and declare a style on all of them at once. The main point however, is that in order for an HTML document to be as clean and semantic as possible, it needs to contain the least amount of presentational markup as possible.

Comment: I used to kick myself for doing this type of thing because "it's a bad idea" but I use the odd class like "cb" for clear:both on clearing divs (which I find helps reduce a lot of cross-browser issues from the outset) - it's all very nice to have a clear separation of concerns but you actually have to get work done at some point too. I think you could argue that giving each clearing div a unique ID and then adding identical CSS is an overhead in itself in relation to development time and page weight.

Comment: @Rob If you have a good command over CSS, you shouldn't ever need a “clearing div”. If you're floating elements to make blocks sit next to each other, maybe you should look into using `display:inline-block;` instead? Of course, that declaration is not without its own gremlins.

Comment: `The main point however, is that in order for an HTML document to be as clean and semantic as possible, it needs to contain the least amount of presentational markup as possible.` Nice. This is what made me start rethinking my approach. Too much junk in the class arena :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't quite agree with that statement. I'd rather see 6 classes and a clean CSS file than 5 classes and a CSS file which uses loads of selectors just to assign a position to them. It's only one class in a HTML file versus loads of selectors in a CSS file. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Aren't CSS classes by default _presentational markup_? So using a mix of both approaches where it fits might be a good idea. Having loads of elements which are quite similar but have a slightly different presentation make this kind of a necessity.

Comment: Not necessarily. A ‘class’ is just a concept. It's as much used as a handle to connect a ‘thing’ to functionality as it is to connect said ‘thing’ to its presentation.

Comment: @JezenThomas - this is not really a discussion about clearing divs - you'll notice I said I use "the odd class like" - it's not the only thing I do it for. However by your own admission you suggestion isn't bullet proof and I work with a team of expert CSS developers who have a very solid command over CSS and they have a standard class called clearfix which performs among other things a clear:both so I don't feel too bad about using that method when I'm flying solo.